# Java runtime not recognized

Tags: java, sdk, runtime, environment-variables

I m trying to install Glassfish Application Server 3.1. But I get this

[image]

I have installed Java 1.6 SDK, also Java 1.6 runtime environment. I have added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin; to path in system variables in environment variables. Still I get this error when I run the setup. In command prompt, running java and javac return possibilities of commands, running java -version returns me,

java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

so why isnt installation recognizing it ? Also, the browser is not detecting it. However, I could compile and run a java file in command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is the 64-bit JDK (though it should not matter).  Can you check the stacktrace in the install logs, if any?

Another possibility is, Glassfish is using the JRE instead of JDK.  Is JAVA_HOME set and pointing to the JDK location?

Comment: I could not find any install logs. I tried setting JAVA_HOME to jre location and then to jdk location, seperately, one at a time. No difference. Even browser fails to find Java runtime. I am using Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I am sure you have thought of it...but please check JAVA_HOME is set to jdk home dir and not /bin under jdk home

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is not because of environment variables at all. Its because my Windows in 64 bit and hence any 32bit app looks for 32bit jre in system in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6 location. I had to install another jre 32bit version and add path for that and all problems went away. I dont see any other option. If you have one, please share. Anyway, I hope they dont conflict with 64bit version. I will mark this as answer, since the first sentence is actually the answer :)